# Query multiple datasources in Google AppMaker from single search box

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to query 2 datasources from the same text box, how do I update my server side query script?

I've modified the existing Google's AppMaker template for Vendor Ratings and customizing it for our internal use.

Inside the app, I've added a new datasource - Category that has a Many to Many relationship with the Contact datasource.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4GwI.jpg

In the header of the Contacts page the search bar DOES works if I'm looking for something where the SearchText matches a field in the Contact datasource.

I was successful in linking a Dropdown for Category to a new query parameter SearchCategory.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgVwh.jpg

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRxqS.jpg

I can't figure out how to make SearchText also query the Category datasource to see if it matches an existing Category and if it does match, return those contacts too.

I've included a copy of my modified getContacts_ function below.

```js
function getContacts_(query) {
  if (query.parameters.SearchCategory === null) {
    query.where = '(FirstName contains? :SearchText or CellPhone contains? ' +
     ':SearchText or Email contains? :SearchText or CompanyName contains? :SearchText or Website contains? :SearchText or LastName contains? :SearchText or OfficePhone contains? :SearchText)';
    return query.run();    
  } else {
    var contacts = []; // blank array   

    var newQuery = app.models.Contact.newQuery({sorting: query.valueOf().sorting});

     newQuery.where = '(FirstName contains? :SearchText or CellPhone contains? ' +
      ':SearchText or Email contains? :SearchText or CompanyName contains? :SearchText or Website contains? :SearchText or LastName contains? :SearchText or OfficePhone contains? :SearchText)';
    newQuery.parameters.SearchText = query.parameters.SearchText;
    newQuery.parameters.View = query.parameters.View;

    contacts = newQuery.run();

     if (query.parameters.SearchCategory !== null) {  //Strictly enforced, returns TRUE - Category is not NULL

     var category = app.models.Category.getRecord(query.parameters.SearchCategory);

     var categoryContacts = category.Contact.map(function(c) { 
        return c._key; });
     contacts = contacts.filter(function(c) {
        return categoryContacts.indexOf(c._key) > -1;
      });
    }

    var contactsArray = [];

for (var k = 0; k < contacts.length; k++) {
        contactsArray.push(contacts[k]);
}
    var result = contactsArray;

    // Apply paging params
    return result.slice(query.offset, query.offset + query.limit);
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use the search bar to return Contacts where the SearchText matches Category name.  IE. "Retail"

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you explore the 'Query Builder' option within each datasource you will note that once you introduce a query parameter, that parameter has a binding option where you can 'reverse bind' the parameter to a widget on a page instead. What I have done is do my query builder for what I want to search within each datasource and then bind the parameter itself to my SearchText textbox widget.

Comment: I've tried to explore that, I was able to bind my :SearchText parameter directly to the widget on that page for both DataSource - Contact and Category.  The search widget does work for searching the Contact Datasource but it doesn't appear to affect the Category datasource.    Here is a screenshot of my QueryBuilder for the category datasource. 

!https://imgur.com/pN4Z7kM

To me, it would seem, I should be trying to query or filter relations between Category and Contact.

Comment: Which portion is not working? Is it even loading the datasource?

Comment: If I search "Retail" across contacts, since there isn't a contacts which contain that word it returns no results.